# php preg_replace : strip all <img> elements except for a certain img id

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, dom

Here is the function i am using to remove every img element from my wordpress string content:

```
function strip_images($content){ 
                        return preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','',$content);
                    }
```

How could i exclude from stripping the img of a certain id?

Comment: It is possible to do with regexp, but why won't you use phpQuery for example. It's a port of jQuery for PHP.

Comment: how easy it is to implement it in a wordpress project?

Comment: To use it you have just to include one file.

Comment: If the id attribute is immediately after `<img `, it's pretty simple, otherwise I think there's a regex expression that says "don't include something followed by whatever followed by something and not a carrot."

Comment: @Jamil i can make the id right after the <img . how would u solve that then?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/<img[^>]+id="someId[^>]+./
```

Tested on

```
<img id="someId">
    something else
    <img class="someClass" id="someId">
    <img class="someClass" id="someOtherId">
    <img class="someClass" id="someId" alt="Hey">
```

Chooses 1st and 3rd line.

If you do much more such operations on HTML in PHP you can use for example phpQuery for this job.

Comment: what if i want to select all except someId?

Comment: /<img[^>]+id="(?!someId")[^>]*./

Comment: this strip no images :(

Comment: I've tested it with http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php and it works. Please post an example which is not matched but it should be.

Comment: By the way, as I mentioned before. Usage of a library like phpQuery would guarantee that it works as you expect. Parsing HTML is a though thing.

Comment: thanx for your help .it works with your example indeed . but with this portion of content for example it doesn't (i am trying to keep the id='img_menu':<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3165" alt="modif 3" src="http://dev.dune-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/modif-31.jpg" width="200" height="132" />
<img  style="display:none" src="http://dev.dune-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/md_img_menu/menu_egypte/Slider_Une_Plonger-Egypte.jpg"width="900" height="455" id="img_menu" />"